# Data Loader Error Date/Time fields Failed to parse date

Tags: data-loader, datetime

[image]

All of my records are failing to insert for the same error. I do not see an issue with the format itself. I also tried using European format with no luck

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I was able to create a custom format in Excel for date/time that matched SF's recommended format and it appears to have worked.

Answer (score 4):

It appears you've mapped a Date field to this DateTime column. Make sure you're using the correct data type for the field, and that you've mapped the correct field.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Data-Loader-Import-data-for-Date-or-Date-Time-field-1327108684799&language=en_US&type=1

If you don't need the time portion just format everything to be yyyy-mm-dd.